# Unit Testing and Access modifiers in OO

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I notice that in order to unit test each unit in my OO code, I need to set the access modifiers to public, even on methods that ought to be protected, or probably private. Is this OK practice?

```
public class EnforceBusinessRules
{
    BusinessState m_state;

    public EnforceBusinessRules()
    {
        m_state = START;
    }


    public bool isInputcurrentlyFormatted(string input)
    {
        //code goes here to ensure the input passes formatting test
        //modify m_state appropriately
    }


    public bool InputContainsValidStartAndEndTokens(string input)
    {
        //code goes here to ensure that the start and end tokens of the input are of the type available in the system
        //modify m_state appropriately
    }


    public bool StartEndCommandisValidAccordingtoCurrentSystemSettings(string input)
    {
        //code goes here to check the start and End codes match the current start and end codes for the day
        //modify m_state appropriately
    }

    // and so on 
}
```

Comment: Probably not.  Why do you need to directly test private methods (i.e. methods that aren't part of your API)?  If they're complex enough to require separate testing, there's probably an argument that that behaviour should be factored out into a separate class...

Comment: This question would be improved by posting what you have already done in code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unit testing is "Black box" testing. You should only test the externally visible elements. If you test all the internal workings then you can't refactor your code correctly without modifying all your unit tests.

Comment: So you are saying it is OK to not directly Unit test the methods I want to remain private?

Comment: yes. What's the point? If your public methods return the correct value you can infer that your private methods are also returning the correct value(s). Plus it allows you to change these private methods without changing test. If they're wrong they should break the public implementations also

Comment: Actually, unit testing is white box testing. Acceptance testing is black box testing. In both, however, you only test visible (public) APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you need to change access modifiers because you have plenty of code in private members that you need to test, it may be a sign that your class is too large.  Consider breaking the behavior you want to test into smaller classes with public interfaces that you can test.  Your code may be suffering from the [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) code smell.

Remember that protected members are very similar to public members, except that the space of possible clients is much smaller (derived classes only).  You could consider unit testing those methods by creating a derived object which only your test uses.  In this way, you will be testing these methods in the same manner your clients will use them.

Here is one way that you might modify your code:

```
public class EnforceBusinessRules
{
    BusinessState m_state;

    public EnforceBusinessRules(IEnumerable<Rule> rules)
    {
        m_state = START;
    }

    public void Enforce(string input)
    {
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            m_state = rule.EnforceRule(input);
        }
    }
}

public interface Rule
{
    public BusinessState EnforceRule(string input);
}

public class IsInputcurrentlyFormatted : Rule
{
    public BusinessState EnforceRule(string input)
    {
        //code goes here to ensure the input passes formatting test
    }
}

public class InputContainsValidStartAndEndTokens : Rule
{
    public BusinessState EnforceRule(string input)
    {
        //code goes here to ensure the input passes formatting test
    }
}

public class StartEndCommandisValidAccordingtoCurrentSystemSettings : Rule
{
    public BusinessState EnforceRule(string input)
    {
        //code goes here to ensure the input passes formatting test
    }
}

// and so on
```

Comment: Well, I have many private methods because in processing input, I have to consider so many conditions. Given an input of 18, I have about 20 rules to ensure apply for passing of the input.

Comment: @Kobojunkie Create an inner class for processing input.

Comment: It may even be wothwhile to create a class for each rule. Then if those rules need to be used in a different context, they will be fully tested independent of the current code driving them.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are thinking about it wrongly in my opinion. You can infer things without making things public. A property's value  could be realised from a function return for example.

In the case of a protected member. Ask your self what that means. It means that derived classes can access that member. So make a derived type in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is bad practice to expose methods/classes/properties/whatever to the outside world you don't want to expose.  We ran into a similar issue where I work.  We wrote tests that hit the public methods and properties, because those public methods should, at some point, invoke all the private methods.  In the case where you have internal classes/properties/methods you can use the `InternalsVisableTo` attribute to them accessible to your unit testing library.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Comment: this is generally a bad idea. It does get you around the problem, and I have done it myself, but it should be avoided where possible

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are failing to create getter and setter methods so that your private data is correctly [encapsulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

The unit tests should access data via getters and setters.

Avoid instantiating collaborating objects in your class code, [inject those dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead.

Comment: These are methods representing various steps of my process. I decided to break it down so I can separate the steps into units.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test private or protected properties or methods, then you should extract the functionality into separate classes. Each class should only do one thing (Single Responsibility Principle). Odds are that your private methods perform the secondary functionality on the main purpose of your class.

When extracted, two good things happen: First, the code you wish to test is now fully accessible by unit tests. Second, you don't have to worry about it in your EnforceBusinessRules class.